# Fetch data from multiple api but display it in the same future builder

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart, flutter-futurebuilder

So I have multiple API but I can't display the data in the same future builder. Does anyone know what is going on?

```
Future<List> fetchData() async {
  String url = 'someAPI';

  final preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  final key = 'token';
  final value = preferences.get(key);
  var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url), headers: {
    'Conten-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer $value '
  });

  log(response.body);

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return [
      // Album.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body)),
      for (final item in jsonDecode(response.body)) Album.fromJson(item),
    ];
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}

Future<List> fetchDataDetail(String id) async {
  String url2 = 'someAPI2' + id;
  final preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final key = 'token';
  final value = preferences.get(key);

  var response2 = await http.get(Uri.parse(url2), headers: {
    'Conten-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer $value '
  });
  log(response2.body);
  if (response2.statusCode == 200) {
    return [
      // ReadData.fromJson(jsonDecode(response2.body)),
      for (final item in jsonDecode(response2.body)) ReadData.fromJson(item),
      // List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(json.decode(response2.body)[ReadData])
    ];
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}`
```

This is my UI for displaying the data that I fetch

```
class EmployeeList extends StatefulWidget {
  const EmployeeList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static String id = 'employee';

  @override
  State<EmployeeList> createState() => _EmployeeListState();
}

class _EmployeeListState extends State<EmployeeList> {
  late Future<List> futureAlbum;
  late Future<List> futureReadData;

  List<Album>? album;
  List<ReadData>? readData;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureAlbum = fetchData();
    futureReadData = fetchDataDetail(toString());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Daftar Pegawai'),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF8B400),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: FutureBuilder<List>(
          future: Future.wait([futureAlbum, futureReadData]),
          initialData: [],
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView(
                children: [
                  ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                    itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => ListTile(
                      onTap: (() {
                        print('${snapshot.data![index].Personal}');
                      }),
                      leading: CircleAvatar(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                      ),
                      title: Row(
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            child: Text('${snapshot.data![index].namaLengkap}'),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(width: 25),
                          Expanded(
                            child: Text('${snapshot.data![index].id}'),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text("${snapshot.error}");
            }
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the class from 1st API

```
class Album {
  Album({
    required this.id,
    required this.namaLengkap,
  });

  int? id;
  String? namaLengkap;

  factory Album.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Album(
        id: json["id"],
        namaLengkap: json["nama_lengkap"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "nama_lengkap": namaLengkap,
      };
}
```

This is the class from the 2nd API

```
class ReadData {
  ReadData({
    required this.personal,
    required this.riwayat,
  });

  Personal personal;
  List<Riwayat> riwayat;

  factory ReadData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ReadData(
        personal: Personal.fromJson(json["personal"]),
        riwayat:
            List<Riwayat>.from(json["riwayat"].map((x) => Riwayat.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "personal": personal.toJson(),
        "riwayat": List<dynamic>.from(riwayat.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}
```

Also, this is the error message

Exception has occurred.
_TypeError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable')

This error appeared in the second API when I tried to return it.

Comment: Please upload the second api response to find out the solution of others.

Comment: Most likely when you do `for (final item in jsonDecode(response2.body))`, `jsonDecode` is returning a `Map`, which you can't directly iterate over.

Comment: @SaifulIslam i alrd upload it below the first api

Comment: @jamesdlin so how could i make it works? sorry i'm a noob

Comment: for example you could try `for (final item in jsonDecode(response.body).values)` if you dont care about the `Map`s keys (for more options check `Map` class properties)

Comment: @ricardosalampessi You haven't showed the contents of `response.body`.  Nobody can tell you how to make your code work without understanding what data you're trying to deserialize into what data structures.

Comment: @pskink the app freeze, and i can't perform hot restart after i tried those code

Comment: @jamesdlin i add the class that contain the body

Comment: and what do you see if you `print(response.body);`?

Comment: @pskink flutter: {"personal":null,"riwayat":[]} this is what i see

Comment: so you have only one `ReadData` data, not a list - why would you want to use `for (final item in jsonDecode(response2.body))` then?

Comment: @pskink what should i do to make it work then?

Comment: @pskink i use this ReadData.fromJson(jsonDecode(response2.body)), and it doesn't work also

Comment: most likely this is because `"personal":null` - but i cannot be 100% sure as there are not sources for `Personal` class

Comment: @pskink 'Exception has occurred. _TypeError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>')' that is the new error i got when i tried to change the return to 'return List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(
        json.decode(response2.body)[ReadData]);'